# Given a function $f(x)$, is there a terminology that denotes the function $-f(-x)$?

Tags: functions, terminology

I have a function $f(x)$, and I am looking for a word that denotes the function $-f(-x)$.

Something like: "Function $g(x)$ is the ___ of function $f(x)$".

**More details:**

I have a *Buy* function (where you put x and get y) and a *Sell* function (where you put y and get x).

They (naturally) hold the property described above, but one may mistakenly expect them to be equivalent and point a blaming finger when they find out that they're not, so I'm looking for a "clean and simple" way to emphasize this.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I don't think there's a term for this, but in what context do you want a single term? It's always better to spell out what you mean.

Comment: @Deepak: That's exactly what I am trying to do (spell out what I mean, by saying "This function is the ___ of $f(x)$").

Comment: And I'm asking in what context you want a term like that? You've got a couple of very reasonable suggestions in the answers but I don't think those terms are widely understood in an unambiguous fashion, especially if you're using them in a more elementary context (e.g. something in an undergraduate answer). You really would need to define exactly what you mean when you talk about the "opposite of the antipodal map", and at that point, you might just have used $-f(-x)$ to begin with. You see what I'm saying?

Comment: @Deepak: Thank you. I understand what you mean, and you are essentially correct. The context in which this needs to be well understood may also include undergraduate (or more precisely, people with an undergraduate level of understanding). So here is the context: I have two functions - one for buying (where you put $x$ and get $y$) and one for selling (where you put $y$ and get $x$). In nature, they hold the property that I have described above. But one may mistakenly expect them to be equivalent, and point a blaming finger when they find out that they're not.

Comment: @Deepak: Therefore, I am looking for a clean / natural / simple / intuitive way to add a short statement which emphasizes this fact.

Answer (score 2):

I've never found a proper terminology, but I'd suggest *the opposite of the antipodal map of* $f$.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen (for example [here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/fcntrans2.htm) and [here](http://mathbitsnotebook.com/Algebra1/FunctionGraphs/FNGTransformationFunctions.html)) that $f(-x)$ and $-f(x)$ are termed reflections of $f$ over the $x$-axis and $y$-axis respectively. This borrows the more [general term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)) of reflection over a line.

This borrowing means that we ought to be able to borrow other mappings of the plane to apply to functions. Especially one could call $-f(-x)$ to be the reflection through the origin of $f(x)$ or the origin reflection of $f$ where we borrow the terminology of [point reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection).

The borrowing of the terms is quite legitimate since a function is just a special case of a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ and these terms are about mapping subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ to subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ (which in these case happens to be functions).

Note that this is a kind of terminology that is unlikely to be found in written form as it is easier to write "let $g(x)=-f(-x)$"  than "let $g$ be the origin reflection of $f$" (but the later is probably easier to say). Also note that the existence of terms is quite dependent on the (general) need for the term - I guess there's not so much need for a term for $-f(-x)$ so that it would grant a special term.

Answer (score 1):

Using algebraic terminology, we might say your map is $f$ conjugated with the antipodal map.  If $\alpha(x)=-x$, then $\alpha\circ f\circ\alpha^{-1}(x)=-f(-x)$.  In particular, if $f$ is an odd function, i.e. $\alpha\circ f=f\circ \alpha$, then $\alpha\circ f\circ \alpha^{-1}=f$.

Answer (score 1):

How about “The graph of this function is the graph of $f$ inverted through the origin.”

Or in the case that $f$ is defined on $(0, ∞)$: “By extending $f$ with this function we obtain an odd function.”

Answer (score 1):

How about "reflection through the origin"?
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection#Inversion_with_respect_to_the_origin